# VLang `dial_tcp failed`

Tags: tcp, threadpool, vlang

I am trying to write up a simple multithreaded vlang app to call 'http://www.google.com' and 'http://www.bing.com' 50 times each and count the response size. But I am getting `dial_tcp failed` for multiple requests:

Here is the code:

```
module main

import net.http
import sync.pool

struct IResult {
    u string
    c int
}

fn sprocess(pp &pool.PoolProcessor, idx int, wid int) &IResult {
    item := pp.get_item<string>(idx)

    resp := http.get(item) or {
      println('Err [ for $item ]: $err.msg')
      return &IResult{
        item,
        0
      }
    }

    return &IResult{
      item,
      utf8_str_len(resp.text)
    }
}

fn main() {
    mut pp := pool.new_pool_processor(callback: sprocess)
    pp.work_on_items(['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.bing.com'].repeat(50))

    for x in pp.get_results<IResult>() {
        println('$x.u len = $x.c')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the same code with the latest master (`1b9eef7`) and it works just fine both in `run` and when calling the binary directly (`./main`).

Using with `libssl-dev` present on the system. Consider upgrading V and using `libssl-dev`:

```
$ v run main.v
http://www.google.com len = 14969
http://www.bing.com len = 80681
http://www.google.com len = 14982
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14903
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14999
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14938
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14895
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14985
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14996
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14982
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14983
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14998
http://www.bing.com len = 80681
http://www.google.com len = 14932
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14943
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 15005
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 15017
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14966
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14990
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14950
http://www.bing.com len = 81099
http://www.google.com len = 14977
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14976
http://www.bing.com len = 80681
http://www.google.com len = 14924
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14992
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14990
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 15026
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 15037
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14967
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14947
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14969
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14965
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14934
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14937
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 15001
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14984
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 15001
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14969
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14947
http://www.bing.com len = 80681
http://www.google.com len = 14976
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14970
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14949
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14944
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14974
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14989
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14985
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14964
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14965
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14902
http://www.bing.com len = 80681
http://www.google.com len = 15011
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14904
http://www.bing.com len = 80681
http://www.google.com len = 15001
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
http://www.google.com len = 14948
http://www.bing.com len = 80682
```